# showing roots of polynomial $X^{p^r}-X$ is subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have an assignment question,

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristics $p$ prime. Show that roots of $X^{p^r}-X$ is a subfield of $F$ with, with $p^s$ elements where $s \le r$. (Hint example: assume F is finite field with $4$ elements, take $p=2, r=3$ and compute $s$.)

The part to show the roots of $X^{p^r}-X$ is a subfield seems to have already been done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682463/proving-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-are-a-subfield). It seems that $X^{p^r}-X$ has (exactly) $p^r$ roots in $F$.

My confusion: How can the number of elements of subfield have less element than the number of roots?

It might be probably typo in question because **Theorem II.2.2** on this [link](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m6406/csln4.html) states that there are at least $p^r$ roots.

> Hint problem: Let $F = \Bbb F_4 = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ and $f(X) = X^{8}-X$. The roots of $f(X)$ are in $\mathbb F_8$. From here, the roots of $f(X)$ that lie on $F$ are $0, 1, 2, 3$. We compute $s=2$ i.e. it has four elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the field $F$ you are working with. You are right, the polynomial $X^{p^r} - X$ has exactly $p^r$ different roots in an algebraic closure. And the last part is important here: If we assume that $X^{p^r} - X$ factors into linear terms, then the number of roots is $p^r$. But this might not be the case if $F$ is to small. So by "roots", the question does not mean roots in some extension fields but roots that lie in $F$ (otherwise you would normally not get a subfield of $F$).

Regarding your example: Nope, sorry. First problem is that there is no $3$ in $\mathbb{F}_4$, meaning $1+1+1 = 1$. Thus, you have your elements wrong. Furthermore, not all elements of $\mathbb{F}_4$ are roots of the polynomial. So I suggest that you review finite fields first and then continue on this problem.