# Question in proof of the existence of a field of order $p^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, splitting-field

I'm trying to understand a detail in the proof that there exists a finite field of order $p^n$. (Here $p \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is a prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.) I've found questions on the proof of this theorem posted here already, which have been helpful (e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682463/proving-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-are-a-subfield)), but there's a particular detail that is bugging me and for which I haven't found an explanation.

What I understand so far is that the polynomial $X^{p^n} - X \in \mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ has an extension $E[X]$ which contains $p^n$ distinct roots in $E$.  Let $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_{p^n} \in E$ be the distinct roots. Now we want to show that $K = \{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_{p^n}\}$ is a field, so we need to show that $K$ is closed under addition (among other things). All the proofs I've seen for this seem to implicitly assume that $a^{p^n} = a$ for any (nonzero) $a \in K$, without any explanation. My question: how can we justify this?

I have learned that if $F$ is a finite field with $q$ elements, then $a^{q} = a$ for all $a \neq 0$ in $F$. But we can't use this property here because we haven't yet established that $K$ is a field (because that's what we're trying to show!). We know that $c_1,\ldots,c_{p^n}$ are in the bigger field $E$, but $E$ would have more than $p^n$ elements (we don't even know how many), so I don't see how Fermat's Little Theorem could help us here.

Could anyone shed some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every $a \in K$ is a root of $X^{p^n} - X$ so $a^{p^n} - a = 0 \implies a^{p^n} = a$.

Comment: Saying that "all the proofs I've seen implicitly assume [something or other[" makes your question hard to answer. If you want help with a particular proof that you don't understand, then please cite that proof. Otherwise, we are just left to guess why you don't understand a detail in some unknown set of proofs. (I think your real problem is how to show closure under addition and not the property that you are asking about.)

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis: Thanks! (And wow, I'm dumb...may delete this post since it was not a very good question and doesn't have to do with fields...)

Comment: @Leonidas your question absolutely has to do with fields, I had a typo in my answer. My bad! I mean it didn't have to do with *finite* ones (it's a statement about arbitrary fields).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not have much to do with *finite* fields: if $\alpha$ is a root of $X^n -X$ in the algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ of some field $k$, then

$$
\alpha^n - \alpha = 0
$$

and thus $\alpha^n = \alpha$ in $\overline{k}$. The operations are done in $\overline{k}$ where that equality makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thanks, got it! Silly of me to not see that!

Comment: No worries! Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

I see guidoar's answer but I'm not sure if it addresses your concern so I write another answer and hope that I don't misunderstand your question.

I believe what you want to know is why $K$ contains precisely $p^n$ elements (and no more). And among other things as you mentioned, you want to check that $K$ is closed under addition. Let $a\in K$ and $b\in K$. Since $K$ has characteristic $p$, $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$. By induction, $(a+b)^{p^n}=a^{p^n}+b^{p^n}=a+b$, hence the claim.